# Connect to Sybase IQ using C#

Tags: c#, sybase

How can I connect to Sybase IQ database server from C# and execute select commands on it?

Tried connect with `Sybase.AdoNet4.AsClient`, `Sap.Data.SQLAnywhere`, `Insight.Database.Providers.SybaseAse`, but it's all not working with IQ, and nothing found to work with it.

Need full instructions if it's possible.

Comment: you might want to share  what and how you tried and what exactly problem you are facing. Not working then what is it showing ?

Comment: @Amit First one saying that "Column @@pagesize not found" on connection (Google said it's because ASE not working with IQ), Second that needs dblgru17.dll, dblgen17.dll, dont know where to get them

Comment: Post your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

We have used using

> (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(GetConnectionString(DB.IQ)))

for SybaseIQ. SybaseAdoNet is for Sybase DB.